# How do I format the script in a probability table?

Tags: javascript, html, probability

I am creating a table of probabilities. The user is supposed to input the probability percentage in the first section, in the second section they write what they encounter (whatever they want), and in the third and forth section the program automatically organizes which dice outcomes result in getting that answer. Below the dice, there should be text that appears after you roll such as "you encountered a hamburger!" if you roll **31** for example.

Below the table, there will be 2 unavailable images when you run the code. Those are supposed to be 2 10-sided-dice. When you click "roll" the dice show the numbers 0-99. If anyone can tell me how to add the images to Stack Overflow, I will do that. The dice already work, they just don't contribute to finding what the "encounter" is.

You might be wondering what I need assistance with because I probably didn't explain it the best.

**Basically, how do I make it so that when I put the probability percentages in the first column of text boxes, the dice outcomes shows up in the third and fourth column?**

the top row in the probability table is what it should be like and the following 3 are visuals of how it should work.

It will all make more sense if you run the code and kinda see what im describing here. I can answer questions if anyone is confused.

```html
<!--Daniel-->
<!-- Nov 20, 2017-->

<doctype! html>
<html>
<body>

<head>
<title>Wandering Monster Table</title>
</head>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Probablility Percentage</th>
    <th>Encounter</th> 
    <th>Minimum roll</th>
    <th>Maximum roll</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="prob1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="Encounter1" value=""></td>
    <td>??</td>
    <td>??</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5%</td>
    <td>giant snake</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20%</td>
    <td>hamburgers</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>50%</td>
    <td>A wolf dressed as your grandmother</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>99</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>  <!--Declares the possible variables-->
var side0=new Image()
side0.src="d10_0.png"
var side1=new Image()
side1.src="d10_1.png"
var side2=new Image()
side2.src="d10_2.png"
var side3=new Image()
side3.src="d10_3.png"
var side4=new Image()
side4.src="d10_4.png"
var side5=new Image()
side5.src="d10_5.png"
var side6=new Image()
side6.src="d10_6.png"
var side7=new Image()
side7.src="d10_7.png"
var side8=new Image()
side8.src="d10_8.png"
var side9=new Image()
side9.src="d10_9.png"
</script>

<center>

<h1>Wandering monster table</h1>



<img src="d10_0.png" name="die1">
<img src="d10_0.png" name="die2">
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click here to roll" onClick="roll()">
</form>
</center>

<script>      <!--Randomly chooses a variable between 0 and 5-->
function roll(){
 
var random=Math.round(Math.random()*10)
document.images["die1"].src=eval("side"+random+".src")
var random2=Math.round(Math.random()*10)
document.images["die2"].src=eval("side"+random2+".src")
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the program automatically organizes which dice outcomes result in getting that answer"  Do you have a function for that?  If you fire it `onChange`  or `onBlur` or from your input boxes, then you can just update the subsequent boxes using `innerHTML`.

Comment: Would I need one function for the whole code or multiple functions?

Comment: That's really up to you.  Imho, you should seek to DRY up the JS code you already have here before going to the next thing.